# how to remove css from a particular element

Tags: html, css

```
<section class="our-gallery" id="gallery">
<h3 class="text-center slideanim">Our Gallery</h3>
<p class="text-center slideanim">Lorem Ipsum is and typesetting industry.</p> 
<div class="container">
<div class="content slideanim">
<div class="chroma-gallery mygallery">
<img src="images/gallery-img1.jpg" alt="Click" data-largesrc="images/gallery-  img1.jpg">
<img src="images/gallery-img2.jpg" alt="Click" data-largesrc="images/gallery-img2.jpg">
<img src="images/gallery-img3.jpg" alt="Click" data-largesrc="images/gallery-img3.jpg">
<img src="images/gallery-img4.jpg" alt="Click" data-largesrc="images/gallery-img4.jpg">
<img src="images/gallery-img5.jpg" alt="Click" data-largesrc="images/gallery-img5.jpg">
<img src="images/gallery-img6.jpg" alt="Click" data-largesrc="images/gallery-img6.jpg">
<img src="images/gallery-img7.jpg" alt="Click" data-largesrc="images/gallery-img7.jpg">
<a href="abc.com"><img src="images/gallery-img8.jpg" ">     </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- /Our Gallery -->
```

in the last one image href link is nor working it only zooming the image like other one. it using css of others

Comment: show your css of `<div class="chroma-gallery mygallery">`

Answer (score 1):

You have an **extra apostrophe** at the end of the *image tag* on the last item.

```
<a href="abc.com"><img src="images/gallery-img8.jpg" "></a>
```

**Should be**

```
<a href="abc.com"><img src="images/gallery-img8.jpg"></a>
```

instead.

Also, **if you want the image not to use the same CSS** as the others *move it outside of the* `<div>`